# maven installation taking 167MB of space

Tags: maven

I am following the step given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/) for installing maven3. The space estimation is 167MB..!

> 1. Can anyone explain what exactly is going to install?
> 2. Is it really worth installing all the libs?
> 3. what is `apt-cache search maven` doing?

Answer (score 1):

I just reordered your question and answered

> 3>what is apt-cache search maven doing?

This command used to get a list with all available packages related to Maven.  Basically we can search for the maven package using  this command.

> 2>Is it really worth installing all the libs?

Depends, in which package you are interested.

> 1>Can anyone explain what exactly is going to install?

Latest version of the Apache Maven.

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

If you execute the above command, it will install latest version of the Apache Maven on your system.

Comment: I think its in-correct / fully not correct because, maven is not more than 6 MB. So after i run `apt-cache search maven` if i run `apt-get install maven` the installation is trying to install all the packages. Now why do we need all these packages when i am already able to run maven without them.

Comment: When we run maven these plugins will be downloaded anyway if they are needed. Running the above command will explicitly download them before time so its better to download them on need basis or if we are aware of all the plugins we need them we can even download one by one.